# Conjecture: the sequence of sums of all consecutive primes contains an infinite number of primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Starting from 2, the sequence of sums of all consecutive primes is:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}2 &=& 2\\
    2+3 &=& 5 \\
    2+3+5 &=& 10 \\
    2+3+5+7 &=& 17 \\
    2+3+5+7+11 &=& 28 \\
    &\vdots&
\end{array}
$$
If the $n^\text{th}$ prime is $P_n$, then we can write $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n P_n$.

I conjecture that the sequence $S_n$ contains an infinite number of primes.

I doubt I'm the first person ever to think this, but I cannot find reference to the idea, nor can I conceive a proof, nor a disproof.  Computationally, it can be verified that
    $$S_{13,932}=998,658,581=P_{50,783,012},$$
and the sequence shows no sign of slowing down.

Can you prove the sequence $S_n$ contains an infinite number of primes?

Comment: very hard to believe a proof is possible, when we can not prove that there are infinitely many primes $n^2 +1$

Comment: I don't get it. Didn't $S_n$ contain exactly $n$ primes?

Comment: @Mathlovin: Yes but he's conjecturing that the sum $S_n$ is a prime number for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: It also appears, for any fixed $m$, that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $S_n-S_m$ is prime.  I.e., we can start the sum from any prime number, it doesn't have to start at 2.

Comment: I am surprised that the sequence 2,5,17,29,59,101 does not appear in the OEIS. I would recommend adding it.

Comment: Standard heuristics would predict that the number of $n\le x$ for which $S_n$ is prime is asymptotic to $x/(2\log x)$ (and computation seems to bear this out). But I agree it's hopeless to expect a proof that there are infinitely many prime $S_n$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A013918

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/153656/12357

Answer (score 11):

As Will Jagy points out, a proof is probably out of reach, but the statement is probably true.

One can give a heuristic argument. The $n$-th prime is roughtly $n\log n$, so $S_n$ is roughly

$$S_n \approx \sum_{i=1}^n i \log i \approx \frac{n^2(2\log n - 1)}{4}.$$

The density of primes around $x$ is approximately $1/\log x$, so the probability that $S_n$ is prime is roughly

$$1/\log\left(\frac{n^2(2\log n - 1)}{4}\right) \approx \frac{1}{2\log n + \log(2\log n-1) - \log 4} \approx \frac{1}{2\log n}.$$

So the expected number of primes among $S_1, \dots, S_n$ is roughly

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2\log i} \approx \frac{\text{li}(n)}{2},$$

which goes to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

(I just saw that Greg Martin came to the same conclusion in the comments.)

Comment: The bound for $\sum_{p \leq n} p$ you gave is too rough, why not improve it by successive partial sums? Also, perhaps improve the probabilistic arguments by coming up with bounds instead of asymptotics? In any case, the above heuristic can be definitely improved.

Comment: @BalarkaSen No doubt it can be improved.

Answer (score 6):

The recent paper by Romeo Meštrović on arXiv at [Curious conjectures on the distribution of primes among the sums of the first $2n$ primes](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1804.04198) states your conjecture, along with certain details in section $3$ such as an estimate of the number of primes (e.g., that your sequence $S_n$ asymptotically has $\frac{n}{2\log n}$ primes). This paper's other sections examine the distribution of primes in the sequence (using heuristic, computational and analytic arguments) to show they are quite similar to the distribution of primes among the positive integers.

Comment: Nice reference!

Answer (score 1):

Looking for "prime partitions" might help to find prior information for this conjecture.

Another conjecture would be the sum of the gaps of consecutive primes, $g_n = p_{n+1} - p_n$: $$s = \sum_{i=1}^{n}g_i,$$ having an infinite number of primes. Considering the fact that the next prime is $p_{n+1} = s + 2$ one might think it be easy, but it is not.

Comment: The sum you mentioned is $p_{n+1}-2$, the conjecture you mentioned is therefore equivalent to the twin prime conjecture.